# Dúvida com wp types

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou usando o WP Types, para um site catalogo de produtos. Criei categorias, sub-categorias e linhas, todas como custom post types e uma filha da outra, de modo que no cadastro do produto, seleciono cada item desses para ele. Porem na página do produto não consigo exibir o nome da categoria.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow em Português! Tente colocar o título da pergunta relacionado com a sua dúvida e não vago como está atualmente. Tente ser mais especifico no corpo da pergunta e se possível colocar o código que já tenha feito e onde se encontre o problema. Veja o nosso [tour]

Comment: Olá, dá uma olhada nesse link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso o Types em um projeto. A categorização depende de como você montou a estrutura do type, e como você chamou a tag da taxonomia que vai usar.
No meu caso, eu usei dois tipos de categoria.

Toda vez que quero exibir um tipo delas, eu chamo assim no view do theme:

```
<?php 
            global $wp_query;
            $term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
            $title = $term->name;
            echo $title;
            ?>
```

Qualquer coisa, é só consultar a documentação do Types [neste link.](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/types)
Eles tem uma FAQ muito boa.